# Cannot create Google Hangout Event link with eventNamedHangout for GSuite account

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace, odoo-13, hangouts-api, google-hangouts

I am trying to create a Google Hangout link and insert it into a calendar event for a GSuite account.

From the Google API documentation, I need to use `eventNamedHangout` as the type of `conferenceType` but the API responded back with a Google Meet link instead.

How can I create a Hangout link for the G-Suite account?

Answer (score 0):

> Hangouts Meet and Hangouts Chat were rebranded to Google Meet and Google Chat in April 2020. Google Meet is enterprise-grade video meetings for everyone. Google Chat is a messaging platform for teams.

Therefore, when you are creating an event with a link for a video meet, the Google Meet link will be the one attached to the event.

#### Reference

- [Google Meet](https://apps.google.com/meet/)